# Should the sort/filter changes throw the focus on first page or current page?

Tags: filter, data-tables, pagination, sorting

If a user is on certain page out of several in a pagination of a table data, when he/she applies a filter/sort, should he 
-be shown results starting on page one or 
-be kept on the same page state?

Comment: If (depending on the UI) an item is selected, then for changes in sorting especially I'd more often than not want that item to remain highlighted (and visible) afterwards (e.g. viewing a list of emails in their default chronological order, I might highlight one and click on sort-by-sender to see all emails from the person). If I _don't_ need to stay on the same item, I can easily go to the top/bottom/wherever, much more easily than re-finding the item when I _do_ want to keep it visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since using a sort or filter of any kind will most likely change the order and the amount of data displayed, the best approach would be taking the user back to the first page. Keeping him on the current page may be confusing and he/she could easily miss some of the data.

Answer (score 0):

This is good question. As per my opinion filter effect should apply in all pages until or unless you clear it or reset it.

Comment: What's the rationale behind your opinion?

Comment: I think he misunderstood the question